# Finding a column vector.

Tags: vectors

**Question:** Given that column vector **AB** is $AB=<a,3>$ and column vector **AC** is $AC=<-5,0>$, Find the value of a if the vectors **AB** and **AC** are two sides of a rhombus.

I thought of solving it using the magnitude of the two vectors **AB** and **AC** but I don’t know how to relate the two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Vectors $AB$ and $AC$ start from the same point ($A$)
- Rhombi have equal side lengths.
- Hence $\|{AB}\| = \|{AC}\|$
- Find the magnitude of each, set them equal to each other, and solve for $a$.